# Maven download .jar file but I can't import it in Code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jasypt

I added a new dependency to my pom.xml like I always do and as expected Maven downloaded the .jar file which is needed (jasypt-1.9.0.jar). I can see it in the Maven Dependencies in the Project Explorer of MyEclipse.

However I am not able to use any of the functionality provided by this jar because I cannot import any classes, the only thing I can do is the following:

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.*;
```

But what I need is

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncyptor;
```

I am aware that the first option should include the second one, but this is not the case. Nothing is imported here. There is not a single implementation found in org.jasypt.util.text as the autofill shows. 
According to the official documentation adding the dependency should be enough and you should be able to start right away.

What is missing here? I never experienced those problems before.

EDIT:
The depency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The repository

```
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Please show the dependency you are trying to use (artifactId, groupId, and version).

Comment: Please Show the pom file and the Project structure will also help

Comment: I added the depency to the question above

Comment: Did you run Maven/Update Project? (i.e. sync `pom.xml` with Eclipse).

Comment: Sure, I did everything I can within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the project (ALT + F5). Make sure that you force updates (box below).
2. If it doesn't help: Build the project (e.g. with `clean package`) and see if there are any errors.
3. If not, you are fine. If so, and you don't understand them, use them to ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Change to a newer version of `jasypt` by updating the dependency in the POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

recompiling the project with

```
mvn package
```

will download the new jar file.